# Conditions for $p$-divisible group to come from an abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$, are there any known sufficient conditions on a $p$-divisible group for it to come from an abelian variety?